# getting blank json response while fetching images url from database via php api

Tags: php, mysql, json, api

Code to fetch all images from server . I am saving the url of the
images present in my server path/directory to the  SQL database (name : photos , columns :id and image )

```
<?php

     $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","webkuv1c_naman","naman","webkuv1c_android_api") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
     $sql = "select image from photos";
     $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
     $result = array();

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
         array_push($result,array('url'=>$row['image']));
     }

     echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

     mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I am getting following response on hitting API :

```
{"result":[]}
```

this is the image path/url : `http://webkunj.com/android_api/productUpload/0.png`

Comment: Show your php code properly .

Comment: It is a good practice to generate random string for image name instead of any number or original name.

Answer (score 0):

You have made all things properly
just replace

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","webkuv1c_naman","naman","webkuv1c_android_api") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
```

with

```
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","webkuv1c_naman","naman","webkuv1c_android_api") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
```